# reading data from zip file in install shield

Tags: windows-installer, installshield

I am creating installer for my data files,The data files are present inside the zip folder,I want that whenever user clicks on installer the data files inside the zip should be extracted to specified folder.

Answer (score 0):

Just create custom action which will extract your files to specified folder.
For example: Add to installation your DATA.zip and 7za.exe (console utility from 7Zip). Create custom action which runs 7za with needed parameters (Archive file, specified dir, etc...) and it extracts your files.